# Kendo Chart - does not redraw if I open deveoper options window

Tags: kendo-chart

[Step 1: Open demo code in http://dojo.telerik.com/IFixu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGZ5W.png)

[Step 2: Press F12 to open developer options in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4fs6.png)

Why graph is not rendered as per available size?

Comment: Worst part, why graph rendered entirely different in IE  http://i.stack.imgur.com/bFR5T.png

Comment: One more example http://dojo.telerik.com/IdANA/2

Comment: I fixed this by adding resize() in $timeout().